# How to connect the yii2 project to React project?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, post, get, yii2

I have server in yii2 and the react app. I need to send the messages from React to Yii2 and get the answer.

I tried to send using 'fetch', but the error was that the connection is week. What way is better to use in this situation?

Comment: Can you use https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start for API

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.